# ¿Almacenar nombre de usuario logeado?

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de almacenar el nombre del usuario que actualiza datos en una tabla, solo he logrado almacenar el nombre de quien guarda datos por primera vez, pero no de quien actualiza, otra duda es; puedo guardar únicamente el nombre, no el ID, para no relacionar con la tabla users. . Dejo acá parte del código.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request,[
        'id_estado'=>'required',
        'observaciones'=>'required',
        'autorizacion' => Auth::user(),
        ]);
    Deposito::find($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('depositos.autorizacion')
            ->with('success', 'Deposito actualizado');
}
```

Comment: Y en la tabla users has creado una columna nombre ?

Comment: Sí, utilizo la tabla Users que se crea por defecto en laravel cuando habilitas el login.

Comment: En el método store logro guardar el ID de quien ingresa información, para lo cual tengo relacionadas 2 tablas, users y depósitos, pero necesito almacenar el nombre y no el ID de quien actualiza en la tabla depósitos.

Comment: para acceder al nombre de la persona logueada podrías usar Auth::user()->username (creo que username es el nombre que da laravel a la columna)

Comment: Utiliza name, pero no almacena ningún valor, tampoco genera algún error.

Comment: Pero veo tu estás usando un update($request->all()) entonces en ningún momento estás enviando el nombre del usuario, a no ser que crees un campo nuevo en el formulario de tipo hidden y se almacene el nombre ahí

Comment: Perdón por mi ignorancia, pero soy nuevo en laravel, me podrías decir cómo se crea ese campo en el formulario?

Comment: Muéstrame tu formulario ! como los tienes o como los construyes

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he resuelto cambiando la forma en la cual hacia el update, y utilizando lo que me has dicho `Auth::user()->name;`  quedo de la siguiente forma por si alguien lo necesita. Gracias @CamiloVasquez

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $deposito = Deposito::findOrFail($id);
    $deposito->id_estado = $request->id_estado;
    $deposito->observaciones = $request->observaciones;
    $deposito->autorizacion = Auth::user()->name;
    $deposito->save();
    return redirect()->route('depositos.autorizacion')
            ->with('success', 'Deposito actualizado');
}
```

Comment: Exacto, podías hacerlo de dos formas o agregando el campo al form o haciendo el update de otra forma válida en Laravel, que bueno que te sirvió, saludos !